# Excel Interop Saving to synced google drive

Tags: c#, excel, save, interop

When I save  Excel on a synced folder of Google Drive I get error that file is inaccessible. I can't save programmaticly on google drive synced folder.

I use:

`Workbook.SaveAs(Path)`

On normal path like c:\myFolder\ everything works fine.

[Here is my project:](https://github.com/sebastraszewski/SymbiozaITExcel.git)